# setting the lower limit for random number function

Tags: java, jsp

How to set the lower limit for this

```
<%= (int) (Math.random() * 60) %>
```

Now it give number from 0 to 60 if i want number in between 50 to 60 so how to set it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    <%= (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 50) %>
```

That is,

```
   <%= (int) (Math.random() * (Max-Min) + Min) %>
```

Comment: Note that this will give you values between 50 and 59, inclusive. Perhaps that is what the @user667340 wanted, but it's good to be clear on that, since with integers, that's not always safe to assume. That's one reason why BalusC's answer (using nextInt) is a little clear, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Better use [`java.util.Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

```
Random random = new Random();
// ...
int i = 50 + random.nextInt(11);
```

*(note that [`nextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) is exclusive)*

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, Java code should be placed in Java classes rather than JSP files.

Comment: That assumes that OP wants a number between 50 and 60 _inclusive_. Usually the upper bound is exclusive.

Comment: @Ted: Yes, that's how I understood the question. @user667340, if you want it to exclude 60, then you need `nextInt(10)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`(Math.random() * 10)` will give you a random number between 0 and 10.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to translate that to between 50 and 60...